# CSS Style Side Navbar with Icons

Tags: html, css, sass

I am currently building a dashboard for a project I'm workig on - as i didn't touch css for years now i kinda struggle with a side Nav Bar.

```html
<div id="nav">
  <div id="nav-wrapper">
    <ul>
      <li><a href=""><i class="fas fa-home"></i></a></li>
      <li><a href=""><i class="fas fa-home"></i></a></li>
      <li><a href=""><i class="fas fa-home"></i></a></li>
      <li><a href=""><i class="fas fa-home"></i></a></li
      <li><a href=""><i class="fas fa-home"></i></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div> <!--End of nav-wrapper-->
</div> <!--End of nav-->
```

```css
#nav{
    width: 10%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #273138;
    position: fixed;

    a{
        color: white;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    #nav-wrapper{
        padding: 30px 0px 30px;
        font-size: 2em;
    }
}
```

This is what my navbar basicaly looks like. I want the elements centered and rounded - similarly to the style discord uses for it's server list ([Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qINCC.png))
Any idea how i can build this in css?

Answer (score 1):

I have created a solution in JSFiddle

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/21spL8e3/9/)

```
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

#nav {
  width: 10%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #273138;
  position: fixed;
}

#nav-wrapper {
  font-size: 1.5em;

}

#nav-wrapper ul {
  display: block;

}

#nav-wrapper li {
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #d24d57;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  border-radius: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
}

#nav-wrapper li a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have made something, does it looks like what you want?

```
body{
  margin: 0px;
}
#nav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 10%;
  background-color: #273138;
  position: fixed;
}
#nav-wrapper{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
ul{
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
li{
  margin-top: 2px;
  background-color: orange;
  border-radius: 100%;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 2em;
}
a{
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

plus, this is not recommended to nest classes

Answer (score 0):

I hope this can help you.

```css
body {
  background-color: #36393e;
}

#nav {
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #1f2125;
  position: fixed;
}
#nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}
#nav ul::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  top: 15px;
  left: 25%;
  background-color: #2E3136;
  width: 50%;
  height: 1px;
}
#nav ul::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  bottom: 15px;
  left: 25%;
  background-color: #2E3136;
  width: 50%;
  height: 1px;
}
#nav ul li {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 10px;
}
#nav a {
  background-color: #2E3136;
  border-radius: 100%;
  padding: .5em;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
#nav a {
  animation: hover-out 0.6s ease;
}
#nav a:hover, #nav a:focus {
  animation: hover-in 0.8s ease forwards;
}
#nav a i {
  font-size: 1em;
}
#nav #nav-wrapper {
  font-size: 2em;
}

@keyframes hover-in {
  0% {
    border-radius: 100%;
    background-color: #2E3136;
  }
  40% {
    border-radius: 12px;
  }
  70% {
    border-radius: 16.7px;
  }
  80% {
    background-color: #7289DA;
  }
  100% {
    border-radius: 15px;
    background-color: #7289DA;
  }
}
@keyframes hover-out {
  0% {
    border-radius: 15px;
    background-color: #7289DA;
  }
  45% {
    border-radius: 70%;
    background-color: #2E3136;
  }
  65% {
    border-radius: 70%;
  }
  75% {
    border-radius: 75%;
  }
  100% {
    border-radius: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="nav">
  <div id="nav-wrapper">
    <ul>
      <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-home"></i></a></li>
      <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-home"></i></a></li>
      <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-home"></i></a></li>
      <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-home"></i></a></li>
      <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-home"></i></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div> <!--End of nav-wrapper-->
</div> <!--End of nav-->
```